# How can I bind the height of a ScrollPane to the bottom of a BorderPane?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scrollpane

I'm working on a simple game at the moment, where you have a board (MapView) and other components like a chat, which all have their own MVP.

Now I tried to implement my board into a `ScrollPane`, no move around on it via dragging the mouse.

The issue is that when I resize the window it hides part of the `ScrollPane` and I can't see all of the board inside of it when I scroll.

**This is the goal:**

[image: screenshot 1]

**This is what is currently happening:**

[image: Screenshot 2]

---

I already tried Listeners, rearranging this panes, different panes, etc. etc.

FXML:

```
<BorderPane fx:id="borderPane" stylesheets="@../style.css" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea">
    <top>
        <ToolBar>
            <Button fx:id="rulesButton" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Rules"/>
            <Button fx:id="optionsButton" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Options"/>
            <Button fx:id="exitButton" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Exit"/>
            <HBox HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS"/>
            <ImageView fitHeight="100" fitWidth="100" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                <Image url="@../neues_Logo.png"/>
            </ImageView>
        </ToolBar>
    </top>
    <center>
        <StackPane>
            <GridPane fx:id="gridPane">
                <Pane minWidth="3" GridPane.columnIndex="0"/>
                <Label fx:id="field" text="Field"
                       GridPane.columnIndex="1"
                       GridPane.rowIndex="0">
                    <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0"/>
                    </font>
                </Label>

                <ScrollPane fx:id="scrollPane" pannable="true"
                            maxWidth="1027" maxHeight="776" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
                    <MapView fx:id="MapView" maxWidth="1027" maxHeight="776"/>
                </ScrollPane>

                <Pane minWidth="5" GridPane.columnIndex="2"/>
         </StackPane>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Im using MVP for the rest, which only connection to the ScrollPane currently is to hide the ScrollBars.

I expect the solution to be very obvious, I just can't see it right now and have been looking for hours, looking through everything I could find on the internet.

Comment: Could you include an image so we can see what you mean by "hides pieces of the scroll pane"? Post a link to an image and someone with enough reputation will edit it in for you.

Comment: This is how it should look like:
https://i.imgur.com/BOhlCPZ.png

This is how it looks:
https://i.imgur.com/XJRN2oN.png